How can I "debug" a failed build on production mode
The project uses Angular 10 and Node 12.22.12
When I try to build my project on development mode (ng build --watch) it runs fine and everything works correctly. However, when I run it on prod mode (ng build --prod) I get the following error log:
[error] TypeError: C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\polyfills-es5.748d34bf10a6f26b2d67.js: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
    at NodePath._getKey (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\family.js:244:25)
    at NodePath.get (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\family.js:237:20)
    at Object.Function (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:271:25)
    at _traverse (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\traverseForScope.js:37:17)
    at traverseForScope (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\traverseForScope.js:19:3)
    at Scope.crawl (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:658:35)
    at Scope.init (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:626:12)
    at NodePath.setScope (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:141:53)
    at NodePath.setContext (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:153:12)
    at NodePath.popContext (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:205:10)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:102:27)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:66:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:113:19)
    at traverseNode (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at traverse (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:53:34)
    at transformFile (C:\Users\[redacted-username]\[redacted-path]\Exploration\src\Exploration\Web\Client-App\exploration\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:107:29)


The error Cannot read property 'params' of undefined is as generic as it gets, and since I am not using the @babel/traverse library myself (I suppose it's a sub-dependency of a lib that I do use) I can't figure out the error.
I generated the sourceMap of the build but I can't get any useful information out of it.
One thing I noticed, the polyfil file that gets generated has a different name than the error suggests, in case of this particular build it's polyfills-es2015.532602ff2bab781a398b vs the polyfills-es5.748d34bf10a6f26b2d67.js suggested by the log file)
This is my angular configuration:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "exploration": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../../wwwroot/dist/exploration",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/*",
              "src/app/images"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "@ahryman40k/ts-fhir-types"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "20mb",
                  "maximumError": "50mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "60kb",
                  "maximumError": "100kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "exploration:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "exploration:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "exploration:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/*",
              "src/app/images"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "exploration:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "exploration:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "exploration"
}


Even though I am currently using Angular 10, and if it's not much of a hassle, I'd like to know how to "debug" this on more recent versions too, since I am also working on several A17 projects.
